# jQuery method .attr() insted of 'id' tracked element returning undefined. Waypoints plugin is used for tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, attr, jquery-waypoints

```
<body>
<div id="wayp-1" class="tracked">WAY</div>
<div id="wayp-2" class="tracked">WAY</div>
<div id="wayp-3" class="tracked">WAY</div>
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.tracked').waypoint(function(){
        alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    })
</script>
```

For some reason this code returns undefined.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please

Comment: Are you sure `$(this)` is referring to the element that was scrolled on?

Comment: 1st: give us the full error or its just undefined??.. 2nd: where is the link of this plugin?

Comment: Not the issue here, but in a general sense `this.id` is a much nicer way to retrieve an element's ID than `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on *Waypoints* documentation, this plugin will not accept `$(this)` as revealed element, instead they suggested to use `this.element` when you are using *jQuery*. Your code should be edited in this way:

jQuery:

```
$('.tracked').waypoint(function(){
    handler: function(direction) {
        notify(this.element.id + ' hit')
    }
});
```

Or when you are using pure javascript (not jQuery) you can use `this` to access the element attributes, not `$(this)`:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName('tracked'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        notify(this.id + ' hit')
    }
});
```